# 回答受付中に言語やツールのメジャーアップデートがあった場合新しく質問し直すべきですか？

Tags: 討議, 質問の仕方, 編集

2ヶ月ほど前に質問をして全く回答がつかなかったのでそのままにしていましたが、最近になって回答が寄せられるようになりました。
バージョンを明記したうえで質問をしていたのですがこの2ヶ月間でツールと言語(Xcode+Swift)のメジャーアップデートがあり、質問に関連する箇所にも影響が出そうです。
現在未解決で議論中の段階ですが編集して現行バージョンでの話題に切り替えても良いのでしょうか？あるいは旧バージョンに関する情報としてそのままにしておくべきでしょうか？

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. 回答が付く前であれば質問を編集する。
2. 既に有効な回答が付いている場合、旧バージョンの情報としてそのまま残す
3. バージョンアップしたために既にある回答が有効な解決ではなくなった場合、新たに質問する。